# Can't Find Logan's Scroll?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Here's what happened:

I'm fighting the guy who carries Logan's Scroll. The enemy has only a little health left but so do I - I run off to heal. While I'm healing I hear the death sound.

I run back up to the roof and the enemy is nowhere to be found. Neither is Logan's Scroll.

My only idea is that he fell off the building. I don't have any poison weapons so he didn't die due to an effect.

I've searched everywhere. On the roof, the room below, and the ground. Nowhere is the scroll to be found?

My whole run is based on getting that scroll and I've put in over 50 hours. Did I just F- up everything?

Comment: Have you tried saving the game, quitting, and reloading the save? That's worked for me in the past when characters who have items I need in souls games fall off a building. The items usually turn up right around the edge of the building where the enemy fell off. Not sure it would work in this case, though :/

Comment: Echoing the save/restart method, as it's worked for me getting the Uchigatana near the beginning.  I find the drop usually appears at the monster's spawn point.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments have said, generally, in the Souls games, when an item falls off the map, or becomes inaccessible, what can salvage drops is saving and exiting the game normally back to the main menu, loading the save back up and returning to either where the enemy spawned, or close to where they fell. Most of the time, but not always, (I have had this not work) the item will just be sitting on the ground where you can retrieve it.